# Can't create UBCD memory stick, using Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, usb-drive, syslinux

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to create a UBCD bootable memory stick. I think I have all the necessary files in the right places. Here's what I get:

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~/ubcd$ sudo ./ubcd/tools/linux/ubcd2usb/syslinux --install -s -d /boot/syslinux /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for pwa: 
/dev/sdb1: No such file or directory
```

Yet /dev/sdb1 does exist:

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~/ubcd$ ll /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 May 19 22:44 /dev/sdb1
```

I can even mount to it:

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~/ubcd$ mount | grep sdb
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~/ubcd$ ll /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 May 19 22:45 /dev/sdb1
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~/ubcd$ mount | grep sdb
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~/ubcd$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1  /mnt/usb
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~/ubcd$ ll /mnt/usb
total 8
```

So what do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: I tried Multiboot but still couldn't get it to work.  It wasn't clear whether the drive needs to be partitioned before running Multiboot, but I assume it does since Multiboot objects if you try to load it into sdb rather than sdb1

Comment: Are you trying to install ubcd538.iso. I format the drive FAT32 when using MBUSB.

Answer (score 1):

### UBCD Bootable USB Drive

I had meant to make a comment rather than an answer but am now committed.

I had excellent success using Rufus, (https://rufus.ie/), to install UBCD, It took less than a minute, however Rufus is a Windows program.

**MultiBootUSB**, (Debian / Ubuntu - https://github.com/mbusb/multibootusb/releases/download/v9.2.0/python3-multibootusb_9.2.0-1_all.deb) Created a UBCD Bootable USB Drive that worked for me in both BIOS and UEFI.

[image]

**UNetbootin**, (Linux Version), Did not work for me installing UBCD. I was unable to boot it using GRUB2 either.